# Как сделать заблокированный button если select пустой?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код, который блокирует `button` если `input` пустые, но у меня также есть `select`, который тоже нужно учитывать про блокировании `button` . Подскажите, как сделать проверку и на `select`?

```js
const mainfunction = () => {
  const inputMail = document.querySelector(".element__input--mail");
  const inputPhone = document.querySelector(".element__input--phone");
  const button = document.querySelector(".element__button");

  const testForEmptiness = () => {
    const condition = inputMail.value !== "" && inputPhone.value !== "";
    condition ? (button.disabled = false) : (button.disabled = true);
  };

  testForEmptiness();

  inputMail.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
  inputPhone.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", mainfunction);
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.element__input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.element__button {
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.element__button:hover {
  background: #6f64ed;
}

.element__button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sec {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">

  <input class="element__input element__input--mail" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <input class="element__input element__input--phone" placeholder="Enter text" />

  <div class="sec">
    <select class="element__input--country">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Afghanistan</option>
      <option>Comoros</option>
      <option>Denmark</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="element__button">button && bububu</button>

</div>
```

Comment: У селекта тоже есть `value` (и событие `change`).

Comment: jq select2 используете? Или кастомная стилизация какая-то?

Comment: @InDevX jQueryFormStyler-master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение - сперва добавлять слушатель, и только потом инициализировать плагин jQuery Form Styler-master

```js
const mainfunction = () => {

  const inputMail = document.querySelector(".element__input--mail");
  const inputPhone = document.querySelector(".element__input--phone");
  const select = document.querySelector(".element__input--country")
  const button = document.querySelector(".element__button");
  const checkbox = document.querySelector("[name='checkbox']");

  const testForEmptiness = () => {
    const condition = inputMail.value !== "" && inputPhone.value !== "" && select.value !== "Select" && checkbox.checked;
    button.disabled = condition ? false : true;
  };
  
  testForEmptiness();

  inputMail.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
  inputPhone.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
  // добавляем на jQuery ивент и потом инициализируем плагин
  $(select).on('change', testForEmptiness).styler();
   //добавляем событие на чекбокс
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", testForEmptiness);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", mainfunction);
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.element__input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.element__button {
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.element__button:hover {
  background: #6f64ed;
}

.element__button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sec {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dimox/jQueryFormStyler/master/dist/jquery.formstyler.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <input class="element__input element__input--mail" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <input class="element__input element__input--phone" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <div class="sec">
    <select class="element__input--country">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Afghanistan</option>
      <option>Comoros</option>
      <option>Denmark</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
  <br/>
  <button class="element__button">button && bububu</button>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало (

Comment: Обновил ответ. Предыдущий раз неправильно вас понял

Comment: Все верно. Спасибо большое ! )

Comment: может подскажете, как туда еще добавить проверку для checkbox? )

Comment: добавил checkbox

Comment: Спасибо, за быстрое реагирование )) Но у не работает так. Только если: заполнить все поля / выбрать селект / отметить чекбокс / и потом снова выбрать селект. Тогда включиться кнопка. Но не как положено (

Answer (score 1):

```js
const mainfunction = () => {
  const inputMail = document.querySelector(".element__input--mail");
  const inputPhone = document.querySelector(".element__input--phone");
  const select = document.querySelector(".element__input--country")
  const button = document.querySelector(".element__button");

  const testForEmptiness = () => {
    const condition = inputMail.value !== "" && inputPhone.value !== "" && select.value !== "Select";
    condition ? (button.disabled = false) : (button.disabled = true);
  };

  testForEmptiness();

  inputMail.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
  inputPhone.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
  select.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness);
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", mainfunction);
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.element {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.element__input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.element__button {
  padding: 8px 40px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
}

.element__button:hover {
  background: #6f64ed;
}

.element__button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.sec {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">

  <input class="element__input element__input--mail" placeholder="Enter text" />
  <input class="element__input element__input--phone" placeholder="Enter text" />

  <div class="sec">
    <select class="element__input--country">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Afghanistan</option>
      <option>Comoros</option>
      <option>Denmark</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="element__button">button && bububu</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Да у вас в примере работает. К сожалению у меня на сайте - нет. У меня стилизация select стоит. По этому надо наверное проверку на div ставить. Это возможно?

Comment: а вы обработчик на селект повесили select.addEventListener("input", testForEmptiness) ?

Comment: да,  как и у вас

Comment: не пойму как стилизация на это влияет, меняется класс селекта или option?

Comment: Стилизация создает рядом с селектом div-ы. А вообще нет, не меняет у селекта класс.